# Метки API Яндекс карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть задача: написать мобильное приложение, используя Яндекс карты. Суть приложение состоит в том, что есть одна общая карта, на которой, зарегистрированный пользователь, может поставить метку, и она будет всем доступна(Для просмотра).
Прошу, подскажите мне направление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуйста, библиотека Яндекс API для мобильных платформ:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/mapkit/

Comment: Спасибо огромное!